# what's the best way to pass an array in java

Tags: java, arrays, reference

I want to pass an array to a method but I know arrays are passes by reference, so the original array gets modified. A work around that I found is to create a copy of the array inside the method and then modify the copy, but what is the best way to pass the copy of an array or it will be better to create a copy inside the method. here's my code
take a look at reverse method in ArrayUtils class

```
package com.javablackbelt.utils;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class ListUtils {

    public static void main(String arg[]) {
        String[] arr = {"one", "two", "three", "four", "five"};
        ArrayUtils.print(arr);

        System.out.println();

        String [] reversedArr = ArrayUtils.reverse(arr);
        ArrayUtils.print(reversedArr);

        System.out.println();

        ArrayList<String> list = ArrayUtils.toArrayList(arr);
        ListUtils.print(list);      

    }

    public static void print(ArrayList<String> aStr) {
        System.out.print("list: [ ");
        for(String l: aStr)
            System.out.print(l+" ");
        System.out.println(" ] size: "+aStr.size());
    }

}

package com.javablackbelt.utils;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ArrayUtils {

    public static void print(String[] arr) {
        System.out.print("Array: [ ");
        for(String str: arr) {
            if(str != null) 
                System.out.print(str.toString()+" ");
        }
        System.out.print(" ] size: "+arr.length);
    }

    public static String[] reverse(String[] arr) {
        String[] a = arr;

        List<String> list = Arrays.asList(a);

        Collections.reverse(list);

        String[] newArr = (String[]) list.toArray();

        return newArr;
    }

    public static ArrayList<String> toArrayList(String[] arr) {

        ArrayList<String> arrList = new ArrayList<String>();

        for(int i = arr.length-1; i >= 0; i--)
            arrList.add(arr[i]);
        return arrList;     
    }

}
```

Comment: What is your requirement, don't want to modify the original array?

Comment: Your way seems fine. And maybe shorten down the code (for us).

Comment: Btw arrays are `not passed by reference`. They are `passed by value` of reference. Remember, everything in Java is passed by value.

Comment: @Rohit Jain  that's what I thought, but with arrays is not the case b/c the original array is getting modified.... so either I'm passing a copy of the reference or a reference to the array

Comment: the reference is not getting changed, but the value the reference is holding is getting changed. So, it's better to create a copy of the array in your case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a copy of the array and hence be saved from editing the original array,

1. System.arraycopy( srcArray, 0, destArray 0, srcArray.length );
2. srcArray.clone()

Answer (score 1):

There's no best answer. Sometimes it's normal to modify the passed array (for example, `Arrays.sort()`), and sometimes it's not. The key is to document the method, and have the caller respect the contract.

I would find it normal for a method that returns a transformed array for an input array to leave the input array unmodified, and I would find it bad to have to create copies before passing an array to such a method, just in case. With a clear documentation, there's no doubt.

Collections should generally be preferred over arrays. With collections, you wouldn't have to create a copy to protect yourself. You could just wrap the collection inside an unmodified one: `Collections.unmodifiableList(list)`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to copy the array. There are a couple of ways that can be accomplished, but for this reason it is often easier to use an actual object such as an [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) object rather than a 'primitive' array:

```
String[] myPrimitiveArrayOfStrings;
ArrayList<String> myObjectArrayOfStrings = new ;
```

The latter method (using 'generics') gives you a lot of flexibility in terms of how you utilize your array. It makes sorting, searching, extending the object in your array, and a lot of other things much easier.

That said, the [Array](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html) class gives you some utilities.

For the record, in Java objects are not passed by reference, but rather passed by value of reference. This means that the pointer to the object is copied. If the original pointer is deleted, that pointer still remains. Only once all pointers are deleted will the object be garbage collected.